# brew hanging (seemingly frozen) when installing boost for nearly an hour

Tags: homebrew

Brew has been hanging on this step for maybe an hour while trying to install the `boost` homebrew package:

```
./b2 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/lib -d2 -j2 --layout=tagged --user-config=us
```

This is what it says it was doing before it got to that step:

```
patching file libs/coroutine/build/Jamfile.v2
patching file boost/date_time/local_time/custom_time_zone.hpp
patching file boost/log/utility/once_block.hpp
patching file boost/thread/win32/thread_primitives.hpp
==> ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/lib --without-icu
==> ./b2 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/lib -d2 -j2 --layout=tagged --user-config=us
```

update:
I just ran `brew doctor` and its telling my I've got some compilers that are different from Xcode's standard. I'm thinking this maybe be because of an aborted MacPorts installation just a few days ago. brew doc is telling me to reinstall Xcode which is troubling but I'm considering it

update:
'opened up xcode. installing the command line tools again because its giving me the option to do so

Answer (score 4):

I followed `brew doctor`'s instructions and installed the latest xcode command line tools and it was able to install fairly quickly. A previous macports install was also a factor.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, install latest command line tools. If that doesn't help, you might also have to install the latest Xcode. ( I had to )

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Just some quick feedback.  Your first suggestion just confirms that another answer might work.  Rather than put that in an answer, upvote the answer that you think is helpful (requires a little more rep).  The second part is a speculative hint, which might be more appropriate as a comment (requires a little more rep).